# Custom Flash component inside SimpleButton causing compiler error

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, button, compiler-errors, flash-component

I'm having a strange problem with buttons in Flash pro CS5.5 and CS6. I'm adding a custom component to a button and for some reason I'm getting this compiler error.

> Symbol1_1, Line 8 1086: Syntax error: expecting semicolon before
>   rightparen.

After some research I've found that the FLVPlayback component created by Adobe is also causing the error. To reproduce it, create a button and on any of the named frames ( UP, OVER, DOWN or HIT ) place a FLVPlayback component, then compile the fla. I also noticed other components created by Adobe compile fine when in a button but only if they aren't pre-compiled. Only the pre-compiled components seem to have issues in buttons. Unfortunately I need a pre-compiled component.

Has anyone else seen this? Is there a work around?

Comment: Speaking on behalf of my Flash and ActionScript experience (with 10+ years), in my opinion, relying on built-in components **unless extremely necessary** is the biggest mistake a flash developer can make. For flexibility and extensibility I strongly recommend creating your own classes. Considering buttons are the simplest among those components I believe it won't take long to create your own version.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! Unforutantely I don't have that option. This involves legacy flas that I don't want to manipulate too much, although removing the buttons is the fallback solution at this point.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would better use MovieClip instead of Button. For MovieClips there is no such problem.